# How soon is 0 seconds?

Tags: discussion

It's not a big deal, but I just got the msg "You can accept this answer in 0 seconds." which is an illogical statement in my eyes.

Comment: 0 seconds was 0 seconds ago... no.. wait...

Comment: Were you trying to accept your own answer? In what context did you get that message?

Comment: I'm guessing it's rounding - like if it was 0.412137 seconds away, which, when rounded to the nearest second, would come out as 0. That, or computers have decided to join forces to drive humanity slowly mad with many small nonsensical irritations...